# The Script needs to Derive From MonoBehavior

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

i'm trying to add a script to the Player sprite but Unity gives me this error, can you help me?
[image]

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent (typeof (RigidBody2D))]
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour 
{

RigidBody2D body;

//Upgradable Variables
float moveSpeed = 3f;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start () {
    body = GetComponent<RigidBody2D>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    Movement();

} 

void Movement()
{
    float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    Vector2 velocity = new Vector2(Vector2.right.x * moveSpeed * h, body.velocity.y);

    body.velocity = velocity;
}
}
```

Comment: It appears that the error has nothing to do with the script that you've posted.

Comment: It says CallbackExecutor but you showed PlayerMovement

Answer (score 0):

Do you perhaps mean `Rigidbody2D`? The 'b' should not be capitalised.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add "CallbackExecutor" script, not PlayerMovement one.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the class inherits MonoBehavior. And its type (`PlayerMovement`) matches its file name (`PlayerMovement.cs`).